# YAML file not deploying - Invalid value for '--parameter-overrides'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have a very simple YAML file to build an API Gateway and a lambda function. If I use straight cloud formation commands, it works fine.

If I try to run it with sam, the build takes forever - 10 minutes or so - but does finally conclude. However, the deploy does not work.

Here is the YAML file

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Storygraf backend API

Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3

Resources:
  ExpressApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: dev

  ExpressLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Environment:
        Variables:

      CodeUri: ./
      Handler: lambda.handler
      MemorySize: 512
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Timeout: 30
      Events:
        ProxyApiRoot:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ExpressApi
            Path: /
            Method: ANY
            cors: true
        ProxyApiGreedy:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            RestApiId: !Ref ExpressApi
            Path: /{proxy+}
            Method: ANY
            cors: true
```

SAM Commands

```
sam build
sam deploy --guided
```

Error

```
Error: Invalid value for '--parameter-overrides':   is not in valid format. It must look something like 'ParameterKey=KeyPairName,ParameterValue=MyKey ParameterKey=InstanceType,ParameterValue=t1.micro' or 'KeyPairName=MyKey InstanceType=t1.micro'
```

I have no idea what this error means.

Comment: Can you add the debug output of your sam commands? When you say it works with cfn commands, do you mean it deploys correctly? Because I don't see how it would work with the template you've posted.

Comment: CloudFormation does not allow _ in the key only alphanumeric values, as stated here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/1937